# wpf icon - control panel's programs and files

Tags: wpf

For a WPF application, how does one set the icon that is displayed control panel's programs and files?

I've set the icon under "Project Properties > Application > Icon and Manifest > Icon". This partly works; the title bar and menu bar icons are correct.

In Program Files, though, it's still showing the default icon.

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set this,

```
<Window Icon="sampleICon.ico"></Window>
```

[Setting icon WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon.aspx)

To set icon for program files , try this

Right click on the project name in the solution explorer.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks. It doesn't change the icon in program files, though.

Comment: i modified the answer, try this

Comment: Are you saying set it to "Default Icon"? As I said, I've already set it this way, but to a named icon (rather than default). How does it know what the default icon is?

Comment: Can anyone else please suggest something?